# What is the convention for using Fragments and views in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a ViewPager and I want to use implement fragments for it, but I don't know what is the best way to do it, should I have multiple instances of a fragment with different views or should I have multiple fragments with their own views?

Edit: 
What should I do when I have different layouts, exactly?

Comment: This highly depends on all of the details that you haven't mentioned. Does each page have different layouts? Are the layouts the same but with different content? These details will determine the options you have available for designing your app.

Comment: Each `Fragment` should have its own layout and each layout should have its own `Fragment`. Don't try to dynamically determine which layout to load into a single fragment. This will just cause headaches down the road.

Comment: Thanks buddy, seems convincing.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code on my git.

This includes infinite scrolling along with header that moves along scrolling and clickable pager[view pager with fragments with listview](http://www.github.com/jjastiny)

You just have to replace the fragmented layout to however you want.
Im using this for my own sns and its very speedy. Make sure you have asynctask for any heavy loading

Comment: `u` is not an English word

Comment: Np plz favorite my git tho :)